# Can Electron be used to create an Outlook Add-in?

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, electron, add-in

I want to make an outlook addin to manage calendar events. Can this be done using **Electron** rather than **C#**?

Comment: I am also looking for something similar.  Upvote!

Comment: check this out it might help you https://github.com/NodeRT/NodeRT

Comment: Have you checkout [electron-edge](https://github.com/kexplo/electron-edge)?

Answer (score 2):

The practical answer is: No.

But of course it is possible to a quite high cost.

Some things that would be needed to pull it off:

1. Build tools for generating the boilerplate for a Outlook Add-In (Ribbon implementation, OutlookAddInBase etc) and project files from a configuration file or other markup
2. Proper embedding of Electron in a WinForms application ([discussion regarding that here](https://discuss.atom.io/t/embed-electron-app-into-existing-winforms-application/24258))

The best approach if you want to continue to build the Outlook Add-In is to do it the pure C# way - if it is an complex application and you want to use web technology to build it you can use the [WebBrowser Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/webbrowser-control-windows-forms) (IE/Edge) or [CefSharp](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp) (Chrome) which you can embed in a WinForms application with ease.